# Send email to multiple recipients from array

Tags: android

I store in my Database emails, i query my db to return a list with all emails.Then in my activity i get them all to a String array (String[]) and then try to get them at a single string so to put them as recipients but at the end only takes my last email from the string.

Here is my code:

```
                DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(
                    getApplicationContext());
            ArrayList<String> array_from_db = db.Get_Students_Email();
            String emails = "";

            for (int i = 0; i < array_from_db.size(); i++) {

                 emails = emails + array_from_db.get(i).toString() + ";";

            }
            db.close();

            Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            in.setType("message/rfc822");
            in.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { emails });
            in.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject of email");
            in.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "body of email");
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(in, "Send mail..."));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(Main_Setting.this,
                        "There are no email clients installed.",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

I have tried also

```
in.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emails);
```

and uri parse but still nothing happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
in.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { emails });
```

Requires a `String` array of emails. Right now, you're just concatenating all of the emails into one long `String`, then constructing a single length string array from that, instead actually building an array of emails.

Make the following change:

```
 String[] emails = new String[array_from_db.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < array_from_db.size(); i++) {

                 emails[i] = array_from_db.get(i);

            }
```

Then just use:

```
in.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emails );
```

Edit:

Or, an even more concise way to handle it would be just using the `ArrayList` method:

```
   String[] emails = new String[array_from_db.size()];
   array_from_db.toArray(emails);
```

Comment: I understand that, that's why y have made the long string (and understand that the mistake is at the long string) but at the in.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { emails }); 
cannot accept emails. Says change from string[] to String,that's the reason i have done this.

Comment: Ok works when i changed from new String[] { emails } to emails. Please edit your answer so to accept. Thank's for your help. And also edit your edit you cannot convert from object to string and even if add cast to string cannot do that.

Comment: Made the edits, and fixed the "concise" way - my bad.

Comment: I will accept it but try not to make "bads" because maybe someone will tricked :P

Answer (score 1):

Or you can simply do:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
i.setType("message/rfc822");
String uriText = "mailto:" + email_concactenated_with_commas +
                 "?subject=" + your_subject + 
                 "&body=" + your_body
Uri uri = Uri.parse(uriText);
intent.setData(uri);
```

It's fine to just separate the email addresses with commas and no spaces in the String of emails.  The email application will pick up on the multiple addresses exactly the same way you would enter multiple email addresses from your computer by separating them with commas.