# Sending mail in android

Tags: android, email, android-intent

I am trying to send a mail in android programatically.To achieve this I had written:

```
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    String subject = "Your App "+ context1.getResources().getText(R.string.app_name) +" crashed! Fix it!";
    StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder("Application Name: " + context1.getResources().getText(R.string.app_name));

    body.append('\n').append('\n');
    body.append(errorContent).append('\n').append('\n');
    sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO,new String[] { "abcxyz@gmail.com" });
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,body.toString());
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,subject);
    sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
    context1.startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Everything is working file mail is opening with mail subject and body, but **To: is not showing, it should show abcxyz@gmail.com**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Send email to multiple recipients from array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028268/send-email-to-multiple-recipients-from-array)

Answer (score 2):

You have to use 
`sendIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "abcxyz@gmail.com" });`